# Size div to fit particular element

Tags: html, css, canvas

I'm trying to auto-crop an image to fit behind a canvas (http://webglworkshop.com/js-test.html).

I have a div that contains a canvas and an image, and the css below:

```
div.carouselContainer {
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.webgl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  border: 5px solid green;
}

.backgroundImage {
  display: inline;
}
```

This works after a fashion, but I have to use a hard coded `height` value in  `div.carouselContainer`.

I'd like to remove the `height` property and have the div automatically resize to fit the canvas only.

Is this possible without using the `background` property and not using JS?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the `position: absolute` from the canvas, and place it on the image instead. This makes the height of the container be determined by the height of the canvas, and the image will be clipped by the `overflow: hidden` on the container.

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work. The image overflows, and the canvas is hidden/disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the img tag and use the image as a background-image attribute on the carouselContainer div so the image size won't influence the div size.

HTML:

```
<div class="carouselContainer">
  <canvas width="1505" height="393" class="webgl webgl-head" style="width: 1505px; height: 393.3px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.carouselContainer {
  background-image: url(code/img/milky.jpg);
  background-position-y: 90%;
}

/* .webgl removed */
```

Adjust the background position with background-position-y. If you need to move the canvas you could use margin-top or padding-top now.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to avoid using the `background` property.